# angularJS scrolling not recognized in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, scroll, directive, ng-view

Does anyone know why this basic scroll directive doesn't work when I scroll in a template within ng-view?  I know this is super vague but I can't find anything on the web.  I have tried multiple variations of a scroll directive but none of them recognize scrolling within the  template.  I appreciate any help I can get.  Thanks in advance!

I'm using this basic directive

```
directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                scope.boolChangeClass = true;
            } else {
                scope.boolChangeClass = false;
            }
        scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<ng-view><ng-view>
```

and a basic template for the view

```
<div scroll>
    <blah></blah>
</div>
```

I should also not that I am using the ngRoute to supply views to ng-view.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.  Everything in my code was correct.  The problem is that I had a piece of css that was hiding my overflow-x.  Once I removed that the scroll event started firing.

Answer (score 0):

in my case

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

I used to use directive example

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" scroll="user.password" required>
```

*directive*

```
app.directive("scroll", function () {
    return {
    };
});
```